# Flex HDividedBox prevent dragging

Tags: apache-flex

I'd love to be able to prevent dragging of a HDividedBox's divider based on a condition. for example:

```
<mx:HDividedBox id="hd1" liveDragging="true" dividerDrag="dividerDragHandler(event)">

    <Canvas id="c1"/>
    <Canvas id="c2"/>

</HDividedBox>

private function dividerDragHandler(event:DividerEvent):void  
{  
if (_something > 10)  
    {  
        event.preventDefault();  
    }  
}
```

Any ideas how I can do something like that? And I'd rather not mess with the widths of the child canvases. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i also found out that you can effectively remove drag handles and disable sizing of an HDividedBox or VDividedBox by setting the horizontalGap style value to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not ideal, but a [here's a hack](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/10/11/disabling-dividers-in-an-hdividedbox-container-in-flex/) of hiding the divider controls from [flexexamples](http://blog.flexexamples.com/).

Comment: The website `blog.flexexamples.com` seems to go down a lot (there's an error 403 there now). There's another blog here: http://andrewalbrecht.com/content.php?pageID=104 . The idea is to simply set `myDividerBox.getDividerAt(0).visible = false;`, where the index 0 here relates to the index of the divider (if there's more than one divider being used). If only 1 divider is used, the index is simply 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `minWidth` on your canvas'.  Try that.

The DividerEvent is dispatched on `MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE` in the HBox, and it disregards `preventDefault()` or `stopImmediatePropagation()`, so those methods won't really do much there.  This works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">

    <mx:HDividedBox id="hd1" liveDragging="true">
        <mx:Panel width="100" minWidth="40" id="c1"/>
        <mx:Panel width="200" minWidth="100" id="c2"/>
    </mx:HDividedBox>

</mx:Application>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, neither solution mentioned so far will help me with my problem which is hard to explain. I'll try.

See this component? http://www.meutzner.com/blog/attachments/360/Flex_Finance_Step5.html

There are 3 charts, I'm referring to the bottom chart. Basically, it's an HDividedBox sitting on top of a LineChart.

It is implemented like this: If the HDividedBox is 500px wide & there are 100 entries in chart's dataprovider & each entry represents a day, then 1 day = 5px. I don't want the "range" to stretch past 31 days so child2.maxWidth = 31*5, right? No good. Results aren't consistent.